# Display date object/value from controller to view in Play Framework/Scala

Tags: java, playframework

I have a date from a model that is retrieved by the controller and displayed in the view.  However, the date does not display as a value in the field in the view.

Here is the view:

```
@(intakeForm: Form[Application.IntakeAdd], lookups: java.util.List[Lookup], users: java.util.List[User], intake: Intake)

@main(null) {
...
<div class="element-date">
  <label class="title"><span class="required">*</span>Date Requested:</label>
    <div class="item-cont">
    <input class="large" data-format="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date" name="daterequested" required="required" placeholder="Date" value="@intake.daterequested" />
    <span class="icon-place"></span>
    </div>
</div>

...
}
```

I have the field value as:

```
value="@intake.daterequested"
```

but it does not display any value -- all other values work, just not the date.

The value is stored as a Java Date() object in the model:

```
@Constraints.Required
@Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
public Date daterequested;
```

I am guessing there may be some translation I could use in the view to correct this?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what the date is rendered as by displaying it directly in the HTML, e.g. `<span>@intake.daterequested</span>`

I suspect it will be in the format `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy` (see [the javadoc for Date#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString())) which does not match the required format of `yyyy-mm-dd`.

You can either use a `SimpleDateFormat` in your template to format the date as required, or else create a DTO for `Intake` that already contains the date in the required format.  If you choose the former, change your code to have the following:

```
value="@(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(intake.daterequested))"
```

You can also define reusable date format for the template.  If you have to format multiple dates, it will save creating a formatter for each.

For example...

**The controller**

```
package controllers;

import java.util.Date;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

public class HomeController extends Controller {
    public Result index() {
        return ok(index.render(new Date()));
    }
}
```

**The template**
This demonstrates using an in-line format and a reusable format.

```
@import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
@(date: java.util.Date)

<html>
    @defining(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")) { dateFormatter =>
        <body>
            <div>
                <b>Raw: </b>@date
            </div>
            <div>
                <b>In-line formatter: </b>@(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date))
            </div>
            <div>
                <b>Shared formatter: </b>@dateFormatter.format(date)
            </div>
        </body>
    }
</html>
```

**The output**

> **Raw:** Wed Dec 14 09:36:15 CET 2016
>
> **In-line formatter:** 2016-12-14
>
> **Shared formatter:** 2016-12-14

Comment: when I add the `value="@new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(intake.daterequested)"`, I receive a compilation error `identifier expected but ')' found.`  Is there something I need to do?

Comment: I changed all the formats to MM/dd/yyyy between the model, view, and controller, but it still will not display the date value.  I have to use a String value.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I've updated the answer to put `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")` in parentheses.

Comment: Steve - thanks for the edit, however, I am receiving a compile error: `[error] C:\WebDev\workspace2\BASECentral\app\views\intake\editintake.scala.html:
135: not found: type SimpleDateFormat
[error]                                 </div>
[error] ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 13 s, completed Dec 12, 2016 8:50:44 AM` Is there another formatting I should use?  Or do I need to somehow include the SimpleDateFormat class in the view?

Comment: I added `@import java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to the view (HTML) and it compiles now, but it still will not display the date...

Comment: If you check the page source, what is the output of `SimpleDateFormat.format` in the `value` attribute?

Comment: Here is the page output - `<input class="large" data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" type="date" name="daterequested" required="required" placeholder="Date" value="java.text.SimpleDateFormat@f67a0200.format(intake.daterequested)" />`

Comment: The parentheses are in the wrong place, they need to be around the whole expression of `@(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(intake.daterequested))`.  I've updated the answer with some extra info.

Comment: The parentheses fix worked - thanks - the Dates are displaying correctly!  Appreciate your patience!